# Using a URL parameter for tracking like Amazon

Tags: analytics, tracking, referrer, url-parameters

If you look at the Amazon home page you will find that all their links are using a pattern like this one from their navigation menu.

```
http://www.amazon.com/MP3-Music-Download/b/ref=nav_shopall_digi_str/xxx
```

I would like to track my website like this.   How do I do so?

Are there advantages to parameter tracking compared to using the referrer header? (I know some clients might have referrer disabled but I suppose most clients still have referrer enabled? And they are doing internal links so referrer header should always exists, i.e. unlike from Google search results)

Answer (score 1):

This URL parameters are mainly used to Dynamic websites and shopping websites. This URL parameters are used to access the total data on the database which are related to that URL parameter. Better to use this option under web developer..

Log on to the Google webmaster tools

On the Dashboard, under Crawl, click URL Parameters.

Click the Edit button next to the parameter you want to define for Google. If the parameter isn’t listed, you can click Add parameter to create a new one. Note that this tool is case sensitive, so be sure to type your parameter exactly as it appears in your URL.

Set your parameter as either active or passive (e.g. changes content displayed to the user or has not impact):

For passive: Select No... in the Does this parameter change... list, and then click Save.

For active: Click Yes: Changes, reorders, or narrows page content, and then choose one of the options that appears to indicate how you want Google to crawl URLs that contain this parameter. The table below describes the choices.

> For more information : Search on Google search using this query Google
>   webmaster 6080550

Answer (score 1):

As far as advantages to URL parameters to referrer tracking there are two major ones:

- (As you mention) -- Referrers are disabled in a small number of clients.
- Referrers only tell you which page a person came from, but not which part of the page.  URL parameters can enable much finer grain tracking.  Which section did the user click on?  Which link was compelling?

Comment: >> Referrers only tell you which page a person came from, but not which part of the page. 

very good point! thanks